# Mapping an Integer to an RGB color in C#

Tags: c#, mapping, rgb

So right now I have a number between 0 and 2^24, and I need to map it to three RGB values. I'm having a bit of trouble on how I'd accomplish this. Any assistance is appreciated.

Comment: Is your number of the form 0x00RRGGBB (hex)?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can do

```
Color c = Color.FromArgb(someInt);
```

and then use `c.R`, `c.G` and `c.B` for Red, Green and Blue values respectively

Comment: Hah, I could have sworn I had tried that. Human error, I suppose. Thank you for your assistance.

Answer (score 18):

Depending on which color is where, you can use bit shifting to get the individual colors like this:

```
int rgb = 0x010203;
var color = Color.FromArgb((rgb >> 16) & 0xff, (rgb >> 8) & 0xff, (rgb >> 0) & 0xff);
```

The above expression assumes `0x00RRGGBB` but your colors might be `0x00BBGGRR` in which case just change the `16, 8, 0` values around.

This also uses `System.Drawing.Color` instead of `System.Windows.Media.Color` or your own color class.  That depends on the application.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `BitConverter` class to get the bytes from the int:

```
byte[] values = BitConverter.GetBytes(number);
if (!BitConverter.IsLittleEndian) Array.Reverse(values);
```

The array will have four bytes. The first three bytes contain your number:

```
byte b = values[0];
byte g = values[1];
byte r = values[2];
```